# Get elements by starting withwhat do class name inside another element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010307/get-elements-by-class-name-inside-another-element-with-jquery), but the difference is that I want to select an element by ID, then I want to select all elements that contain classes that starts with a a class name prefix

I tried

```
var x = $('#divID [class^="col-"]');
```

but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown does work, if the class appears at the beginning of the `class` attribute. If it doesn't, you'll need to filter yourself:

```
var x = $("#divID *").filter(function() {
    return this.className.split(" ").some(s => s.startsWith("col-"));
});
```

...which isn't ideal, but unless you're doing it hundreds of times a second, it's not a problem.

```js
var x = $("#divID *").filter(function() {
    return this.className.split(" ").some(s => s.startsWith("col-"));
});
x.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div id="divID">
  <div class="foo col-xs-2">foo col-xs-2</div>
  <div class="foo">foo</div>
  <div class="foo col-xs-4 bar">foo col-xs-4 bar</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Instead, though, give your elements a common class in addition to the `col-` class, so you can select on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer to your question and i have checked this code personally.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divi_d [class^='col']").css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divi_d">
<input name="nationality" type="text" value="Chinese">
<input name="nation" type="text" value="English">
<input class="col-lg-2" name="country" type="text" value="Germany">
<input name="anothernation" type="text" value="Norwegian">
</div>
```

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divi_d [class^='col']").css("background-color", "yellow");});
</script>

please do not forget to include Jquery in the beginning.

let me know if you have any confusion.

Reference website www.webnius.com